# Deploy MDB on WebLogic 10.3

Tags: jms, message-driven-bean

I am new to MDB, so my questions may sound simple.

I implemented an MDB( serving as a Consumer ) using JDeveloper 11.1.7 and built a JAR file using deployment functionality. Now I need to deploy it to WebLogic 10.3 app server. I have several questions:

1) Should I deploy it as a library or as an application?
2) After I successfully deploy and it's in the "RUNNING" mode I assume it should be listening to the particular Queue I specified as a Resource in my MDB implementation. Is that correct?
3) When implementing an MDB all the examples only specify the "destination" but not the "ConnectionFactory". How does it know where to connect to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I deploy it as a library or as an application?

Deploy as an application since the MDB will likely contain business logic specific to the app.

> After I successfully deploy and it's in the "RUNNING" mode I assume it
>   should be listening to the particular Queue I specified as a Resource
>   in my MDB implementation. Is that correct?

Yes, if your JMS provider is local, specify the name bound in the local JNDI tree for the destination using `destination-jndi-name`.

> When implementing an MDB all the examples only specify the
>   "destination" but not the "ConnectionFactory". How does it know where
>   to connect to?

If the MDB is consuming messages from the local WebLogic JMS provider, the container manages configuration for the connections and sessions automatically, so don't set `provider-url`, `initial-context-factory`, or `connection-factory-jndi-name`, unless you have a custom factory to use.

Refer to WebLogic 10.3 [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e15493/prog_details.htm#i1148257) for details: